# Displaying images and memory management

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have around 100 images that are currently 1200*600 and saved in jpegs. To display them on my screen I thought I would use use the Bitmapfactory function to scale them down when displaying. Now as I won't be using the full resolutino anyways I think, in what size and format should I save all my pictures in my APK? Just leave it as jpeg and keep the best resolutiuon I have or convert them to another file format and scale them down to reduce size?

Also there is this out of memory error. Is there any way I can find out if anyone could experience one? After all I have only one phone and it's one of the most powerful ones, so even if I don't get this error someone with a worse phone could, right?

Answer (score 0):

Google have published a great article about how to handle images in Android Apps:

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: I know that, but it doesn't tell me how to save the images and how to find out if OOM errors are possible.

Comment: Ok, and did you try Glide library, as recommended in the top of the article? You can save images in what ever you want size and glide will automatically scale them down to your ImageView size.

Comment: I did take a look at it but I would prefer using BitmapFactory, 

Also I know they will be scaled down, but incase the user has an iPad and I scaled them down before saving it won't look good. But I also don't want to use that much memmory :/

Comment: You should not save scaled down images because you are right it won't look good. But this images should be scaled down (sampled) to sizes of ImageView at a runtime so they will take as much memory as needed to be displayed properly. You can use BitmapFactory, but then you'll implement scaling part manually (public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight)) like it is described in the article.

Comment: Ok great thanks, it works. The only problem is that it's extremely laggy :/

Comment: A library? Or what.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142219/discussion-between-eugene-laminskiy-and-newtoeverything).